Australian TV Series from 70s - Journalist Revived, political future thriller
I'm pretty sure this was only shown on Australian TV. A journalist or political trouble-maker is revived (from cryo?) after decades and becomes involved in the somewhat fascist future government. He starts out against them and ends up reluctantly convinced. I think it may end with Queensland seceding from the rest of Australia and a local nuclear conflict. 
I remember one scene close to the end of the series where the head of security for the main politician is rewarded with a car with a remote control which he uses to kill himself, feeling displaced by the journalist.
Note on the revived thing - I am fairly sure it was something like cryogenic suspension and was literally a put the troublemaker on ice rather than being voluntary. There may have been some future resistance involved in his revival.

What do you mean revived? Like from the dead?

I can't remember but I am pretty sure the "revived" was from some form of cryogenic suspension so have amended the question.

Hah, after seeing the question re-opened, decided to search again and found it! (Via Australian Science Fiction Television Series wikipedia entry)
Timelapse

A science fiction series set in early 1990s, but from the perspective
of the late 1970s. The plot is centred around the character of Douglas
Hardy (Robert Coleby), a computer genius who was cryogenically frozen
in 1979 after an assassination attempt by corrupt politicians, notably
politically rising star Dakin (John Meillon) and his ruthless
supporter Boyd Mackiel (Vincent Ball).
Twelve years on, in a fictional 1991, Hardy is revived from his
cryogenic preservation as medical science has advanced to be able to
prevent his death from the attempted aassination. Still recovering,
Hardy sets out to seek his revenge on those who sought to have him
killed. He finds that the world has moved on in twelve years, and he
has to adjust. He also discovers that his enemies now wield even
greater political power and criminal influence.
Hardy is forced to keep on the run to avoid being silenced once and for
all. He seeks ways to become a public figure without putting himself
at risk, appearing on a new television gameshow that seemed
incomprehensible to audiences in the late 70s (and which would still
raise eyebrows even after Big Brother). Eventually, Hardy gathers
evidence against his enemies in an attempt to bring down the corrupt
government.

I was wrong about him being a journalist but right on my 30yo memory of main plot.
Sadly, it seems very likely the original footage was lost. It's also  listed on fan site australian television information archive but is not in the official National Film and Sound Archive
